# Are there any TLD registrars that support dnscurve?

Tags: domain-name-system

Are there any TLD registrars that support dnscurve?

Comment: What does your domain registrar have to do with what your DNS servers support? Also, it seems that DNSCurve is attempting to duplicate much of what DNSSEC accomplishes. I'd caution you against getting to vested in a somewhat obscure project like this.

Comment: DNSCurve and DNSSEC are complementary, really, the better question is how many implementations of it are there? One? I hope it takes off, but I'm not holding my breath. For a deeper look, check out the Ask Mr DNS podcast where they talk about it http://www.ask-mrdns.com/2010/03/episode-14/

Answer (score 2):

To get DNSCurve working you need two things:

1. The ability to publish long NS records contained the encoded public key in them
2. A namse server that actually supports DNSCurve

For #1, see Ronald's answer.

For #2, your options are *very* limited.  I presume that DJB's own software supports it, but I'm not aware of any others.  In any event DNSCurve only protects the path between a recursive resolver and the authoritative server - it does nothing for the communication between stub resolvers and recursive servers.

Answer (score 1):

[Registrar/TLD Info as of June 27](https://serverfault.com/questions/189917/i-want-to-inventory-the-hardware-of-my-linux-systems-using-only-ssh-on-the-client)

3 different registars were used: register.com, godaddy.com, and networksolutions.com.  All of them accepted and published DNSCurve nameserver names correctly.  In the overall, register.com was the easiest one to work with for someone who wants to manually configure custom nameserver hostnames and IPv4 glue.

So, let you register nameservers for your domain with dnscurve names, any should work, but I don't know that any root server supports it, or will support it, any time soon. If they do, expect a minor one to, not .com or the like.